# Sign .apk file without password prompting on local phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, apk, jarsigner

Hi there 
I am trying to sign my unsigned .apk file without prompting the password. 
The android build is local on phonegap/cordova via cmd/powershell.
The signing-step should be done with jarsigner via cmd too.Unfortunately there is no official option to do it without prompting the password or i just cant find it.
Does anybody know how to do it? 

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I have found a solution to sign a .apk via cli.[link](http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/) its not what i actually planed but it works on a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a build.json file, cordova will pick it automatically when you build your app

```
{
     "android": {
         "debug": {
             "keystore": "keyStoreName.keystore",
             "storePassword": "keystorePassword",
             "alias": "aliasName",
             "password" : "aliasPassword",
             "keystoreType": ""
         },
         "release": {
             "keystore": "keyStoreName.keystore",
             "storePassword": "keystorePassword",
             "alias": "aliasName",
             "password" : "aliasPassword",
             "keystoreType": ""
         }
     }
 }
```